# unsafe.Pointer to []byte in Go

Tags: arrays, pointers, opengl, go, type-conversion

I'm trying to write a screenshot function for my OpenGL project in Go, I'm using the OpenGL bindings found here:

https://github.com/go-gl/glow

This is the code I use to make a screenshot, or well, it's what I'm working on:

```
    width, height := r.window.GetSize()
    pixels := make([]byte, 3*width*height)

    // Read the buffer into memory
    var buf unsafe.Pointer
    gl.PixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
    gl.ReadPixels(0, 0, int32(width), int32(height), gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf)
    pixels = []byte(&buf) // <-- LINE 99
```

This triggers the following error during compile time:

```
video\renderer.go:99: cannot convert &buf (type *unsafe.Pointer) to type []byte.
```

How do I convert `unsafe.Pointer` to a byte array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `unsafe.Pointer` is already a pointer, you can't use a pointer to `unsafe.Pointer`, but you should use it directly. A simple example:

```
bytes := []byte{104, 101, 108, 108, 111}

p := unsafe.Pointer(&bytes)
str := *(*string)(p) //cast it to a string pointer and assign the value of this pointer
fmt.Println(str) //prints "hello"
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Can I ask why it has to be written as `*(*[]byte)` and what does that mean? A pointer conversion to a pointer to a byte array? And how does that become []byte?

Comment: it's confusing and comes from C: `(*string)(p)` means "cast p to a string pointer". The extra `*` before it means "the value of that pointer". so essentially the line reads: `let "str" be a the value of a string pointer cast of p`

Comment: For the purposes of C-interop, `unsafe.Pointer(&bytes)` will create a pointer to the first byte of the slice, which is not the first byte of the *data* (which is usually what C expects)--for this reason, you should use `unsafe.Pointer(&bytes[0])` (of course, you'll need to ensure that you have a 0th element).

Comment: Thanks for the insights you two. I figured out the real solution but I will still mark the answer as valid because it did answer the question.

The GLOW library has a gl.Ptr type that automatically converts to the type you supply in it. (f.ex: gl.Ptr(pixels))

Comment: why this is the answer.. I'm here from Google with title `unsafe.Pointer to slice`. but the answer absolutely not, it's `slice to unsafe.Pointer`.

Comment: @weberc2 Be very careful that this is a very nasty hack. The []byte type is a slice struct consisting of three fields: ptr, len and capa. The string struct has two fields: ptr and len. The conversion from []byte to string *happens* to be compatible, resulting in a string reflecting the bytes and ignoring the capacity. If you modify the bytes the string also changes, breaking the immutability guarentee.  See https://play.golang.org/p/ye9UJts1Zoe

Comment: @HeWenYang That's the point of my comment. You make a pointer to the start of the _data_, not the start of the _slice header_. Also, the question and my comment had nothing to do with strings...

Answer (score 0):

> How do I convert `unsafe.Pointer` to a byte array?

This is probably an XY problem. You don't really need to convert an `unsafe.Pointer` to a byte array/slice from what I can see.

The root of the issue lies at your attempt in passing `buf` to `gl.ReadPixels`. I'm not familiar with the `go-gl` package, but it looks like you should be using [`gl.Ptr(data interface{})`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-gl/gl/v2.1/gl#Ptr) to pass an `unsafe.Pointer` to an *existing* buffer (which I assume is what `pixels` is):

```
    width, height := r.window.GetSize()
    pixels := make([]byte, 3*width*height)

    // ...

    buf := gl.Ptr(&pixels[0]) // unsafe.Pointer pointing to 1st element in pixels
    gl.ReadPixels(0, 0, int32(width), int32(height), gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf)
    // Also could try (I believe this requires OpenGL 4.5):
    gl.ReadPixels(0, 0, int32(width), int32(height), gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, int32(len(pixels)), buf)
    // Access pixels as normal, no need for conversion.
```

---

That said, it is possible to go from an `unsafe.Pointer` to a byte slice/array back to a byte array/slice. To avoid redundancy, I suggest looking at this existing SO question: [How to create an array or a slice from an array unsafe.Pointer in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187973/how-to-create-an-array-or-a-slice-from-an-array-unsafe-pointer-in-golang).

Long story short, though, if you have access to Go 1.17 you can simply do the following to get a `[]byte` slice.

```
pixels = unsafe.Slice((*byte)(buf), desiredSliceLen)
```