# How to inspect slice header?

Tags: go, slice

This is slightly modified code from [slices](https://blog.golang.org/slices)

```
var buffer [256] byte

func SubtractOneFromLength(slice []byte) []byte {
    slice = slice[0 : len(slice)-1]
    return slice
}

func main() {
    slice := buffer[10:20]
    fmt.Println("Before: len(slice) =", len(slice))
    newSlice := SubtractOneFromLength(slice)
    fmt.Println("After:  len(slice) =", len(slice))
    fmt.Println("After:  len(newSlice) =", len(newSlice))
    newSlice2 := SubtractOneFromLength(newSlice)
    fmt.Println("After:  len(newSlice2) =", len(newSlice2))
}
```

It says that contents of a slice argument can be modified by a function, but its header cannot. 
How can I print header of newSlice2 on my screen?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The slice header is represented by the [`reflect.SliceHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader) type:

```
type SliceHeader struct {
        Data uintptr
        Len  int
        Cap  int
}
```

You may use package [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) to convert a slice pointer to `*reflect.SliceHeader` like this:

```
sh := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&newSlice2))
```

And then you may print it like any other structs:

```
fmt.Printf("%+v", sh)
```

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zM1ylEdbd3f)):

```
&{Data:1792106 Len:8 Cap:246}
```

Also note that you can access the info stored in a slice header without using package `unsafe` and `reflect`:

- to get the `Data` field, you may use `&newSlice2[0]`
- to get the `Len` field, use `len(newSlice2)`
- to get the `Cap` field, use `cap(newSlice2)`

See a modified [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Lw131X0e5Z1) example which shows these values are the same as in the slice header.

See related questions:

[How to create an array or a slice from an array unsafe.Pointer in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187973/how-to-create-an-array-or-a-slice-from-an-array-unsafe-pointer-in-golang/51188315#51188315)

[nil slices vs non-nil slices vs empty slices in Go language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305170/nil-slices-vs-non-nil-slices-vs-empty-slices-in-go-language/44305910#44305910)