# go's big.Int underlying value mutates when value points to another instance

Tags: pointers, go

I have come across a bit of unexplained behavior of go's `big.Int` when pointing an instance of one `big.Int` to another.
I am knowledgeable that in order to set a value of a `bit.Int`'s instance to another, one must use the `Int.SetXXX` setters, because they actually cause the underlying `abs` slice in `big.Int` to be copied to a newly allocated array. However, putting that aside for a moment, I'd like to know *why* the following behavior occurs.

Consider the following:

Wrong example (underlying value mutates):

```golang
func main() {
    v1p := big.NewInt(1)
    v2p := big.NewInt(2)

    v1 := *v1p
    v2 := *v2p

    v2 = v1

    v1.SetInt64(3)

    fmt.Println(v1.Int64(), v2.Int64())
}
```

(run here: https://play.golang.org/p/WxAbmGdKG9b)

Correct example (value does not mutate):

```golang
func main() {
    v1p := big.NewInt(1)
    v2p := big.NewInt(2)

    v1 := *v1p
    v2 := *v2p

    v2.Set(v1p)

    v1.SetInt64(3)

    fmt.Println(v1.Int64(), v2.Int64())
}
```

(run here: https://play.golang.org/p/16qsGhwHIWf)

If I understand correctly, the following should essentially demonstrate what happens in the wrong example:

```golang
func main() {
    var a, b *int // analogous to the 2 big.Int pointers returned
    c, d := 3, 3
    a = &c // we set the pointers to point to something we can then dereference
    b = &d

    e := *a // e and f should now point to the values pointed to by the pointers
    f := *b

    // the rest is self-explanatory
    e = f

    c = 5
    d = 4

    fmt.Println(a, b, c, d, e, f)
}
```

(run here: https://play.golang.org/p/cx76bnmJhG7)

My only assumption is that somehow when copying the struct content onto `v2` in the *Wrong* example, what happens is that `abs` slice does not get deep-copied but that the storage that it references is actually the same storage that the slice in `v1` points to.

Is this really what happens? Is this the expected behavior according to the language spec too?

Comment: In the first example, both v1 and v2 will reference v1p after `v2 = v1`, so you're not mutating `v2p`, you're printing `v1p` twice. (this is 100% guesswork since I know very little go). See https://play.golang.org/p/GgdhXXNdB85

Comment: You should never be dereferencing a `*big.Int`, so this should never be a problem. a `big.Int` contains an internal slice (which implies a pointer) which is what you're copying.

Comment: Assigning `v1` to `v2` copies the struct value, which includes the `nat` field which is a slice. Slices are struct-like headers containing a pointer to a backing array. Copying a slice just copies the header, including the pointer, and the copy will point to the same backing array. See details: [Are golang slices passed by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993688/are-golang-slices-passed-by-value/39993797#39993797) and [How to inspect slice header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54195834/how-to-inspect-slice-header/54196005#54196005)

Comment: As you properly guessed no copy in Go is a deep copy. Any struct containing slices, pointer, channels or closures cannot be deep-copied (unless it provides a function/method to do so).

Comment: Going forward, what happens may be implementation dependant. Since you have now 2 struct values (not pointers), calling a method on one that mutates it, the 2 struct values may be inconsistent. The one you call the method, may update the slice elements and other struct fields. Other changed struct fields will not be reflected on the other struct, and slice element changes may or may not be (e.g. if the slice gets extended with `append()`, that creates a new slice header but the other struct will not see this; but if current elements get changed that will be).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by icza and Volker, since when dereferencing the `big.Int` pointer the actual value slice header struct is copied, pointing to the same underlying value, the resulting behavior is that the same underlying array gets referenced from multiple slices, resulting in one altering the other.