# How to manipulate a C character array inside a cgo function?

Tags: c, go, cgo

I have a C function, that is calling a go-Function with an char array parameter. The go-Function has to modify the content of the parameter. How to accomplish this?

```
void cFunction() {
 char buffer[9] = "aaabbbccc"; // 9 is in this case correct, it is not a null-terminated-string
 goFunction(buffer);
 // buffer shall be modified
}
```

```golang
func goFunction(cBuffer *C.char) {
  // how to modify 3-5?
  //strncpy(cBuffer+3, "XXX")
}
```

EDIT: to be more precise. I have to implement a callbackfunction, that accepts an outparameter, which I have to manipulate.

```
  void callback(char outbuffer[9]) {
    goFunction(outbuffer);
  }
```

as I understand Franks answer, I should do something like

```
  allocate new go buffer
  convert C buffer to go buffer
  manipulate go buffer
  allocate new C buffer
  convert go buffer to C buffer
  memcpy C buffer into outbuffer
```

That is too much allocation and conversion for my taste

Comment: Maybe you can convert the cBuffer to a `[]byte` and then you can manipulate it however you want.

Comment: with `convert` you mean to allocate a new buffer? or just `cast` to `[]byte`?

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#turning-c-arrays-into-go-slices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for [Turning C arrays into Go slices](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#turning-c-arrays-into-go-slices) to get a indexable go slice containing the C data.

Because you are modifying the C buffer data in place, using the Go slice as a proxy, you can simply pass the same buffer to the callback. Note that using `append` may allocate a new Go array for your slice, so you need to avoid it and make sure you have sufficient space available in the buffer beforehand.

```
func goFunction(cBuffer *C.char, length int) {
    slice := (*[1 << 28]C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(cBuffer))[:length:length]
    // slice can now be modified using Go syntax, without pointer arithmetic
    
    C.callback(cBuffer)
}
```

Comment: where do you get the 28 from?

Comment: @PeterMiehle: it's just an arbitrary size, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756732/what-does-1-30c-yourtype-do-exactly-in-cgo/48756785#48756785

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommanded to modify C struct in Go, or Go struct in C. Convert it at the interface, [Ref1](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Go_references_to_C).

> A few special functions convert between Go and C types by making copies of the data. In pseudo-Go definitions

More, give you a way to convert string with zero copy, [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187973/how-to-create-an-array-or-a-slice-from-an-array-unsafe-pointer-in-golang).

```
func char2Slice(data unsafe.Pointer, len C.int) []byte {
    var value []byte
    sH := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&value))
    sH.Cap, sH.Len, sH.Data = int(len), int(len), uintptr(data)
    return value
}
```

Comment: what if I have to modify the C buffer directly (legacy-code, i have a callback-function that manipulates the data of the out-parameter)?

Comment: @PeterMiehle I can't get you right. Can you update your question and add this 'legacy-CallBack' in your description and pseudocode?